# how to use notifyDataSetAdapter in listview android?

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I want use notifyDataSetAdpter in my list view. I read about it that i can use it when my data is updating or deleting. In my case, my whole data will show in a listView and this data i am calling from MySQL. Now, I am just displaying DB values into a list. No deletion. I want this method to show updated DB values in a list I tried using this method but it didn't work. Can you please tell me how exactly and where exactly I have to use it, in my case.

Here is my code:

```
See_Issue.java
package com.example.mi.mikpiadmin;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class See_Issue extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

     ListView listView1;
    public static final String URL_GET_ISSUE = "http://10.238.4.175/new/one.php";

    public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="results";
    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_STORE_NAME = "store_name";
    public static final String TAG_ISSUE = "issue";
    public static final String TAG_DESCRIBE = "describe";

    private String JSON_ISSUE_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_see__issue);
        listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_see_issue) ;
        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getJSON();

    }


    private void showEmployee(){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_ISSUE_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

            for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = jo.getString(TAG_STORE_NAME);
                String name = jo.getString(TAG_ISSUE);
                String describe = jo.getString(TAG_DESCRIBE);

                HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(TAG_STORE_NAME,id);
                employees.put(TAG_ISSUE,name);
                employees.put(TAG_DESCRIBE,describe);
                list.add(employees);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                See_Issue.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_STORE_NAME,TAG_ISSUE,TAG_DESCRIBE},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.feedback});
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
       ((ListAdapter) listView1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    private void getJSON(){
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            private ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(See_Issue.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_ISSUE_STRING = s;
                showEmployee();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s  = rh.sendGetRequest(URL_GET_ISSUE);
                return s;
            }
        }
        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, See_Feedback.class);
        HashMap<String,String> map =(HashMap)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String empId = map.get(Config.TAG_ID).toString();
        intent.putExtra(Config.EMP_ID,empId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

I hope you will help.

Comment: where are you making changes to list?

Comment: in method showEmployee()

Comment: I tried using this method in List adapter but it didn't work

Comment: i cannot see you making any changes to your list, you are just creating and send to your list to adapter,notifyDataSetAdpter is used when you making any changes to your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` :

> Call [**notifyDataSetChanged**()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your Adapter object once you've modified the data in that adapter.
>
> It notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

**for exapmle**

```
   ((BaseAdapter) yourListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: hey, thanks but i have i have already tried that and it is not working. IT gives me error of can not reslove this error

Comment: anything else you can suggest?

Comment: ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                See_Issue.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_STORE_NAME,TAG_ISSUE,TAG_DESCRIBE},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.feedback});
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        ((ListAdapter) listView1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: same error to notifyDataSetAdpater() - Can not reolve method. It is showing in red line

Comment: add your code where you are adding your `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in your question @user8380237

Comment: @user8380237 `SimpleAdapter` this class my friend

Answer (score 0):

you have to make few changes to achieve this-

1- make these global-

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private HashMapAdapter adapter;
```

2- Write your own custom adapter class-

```
public class HashMapAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private HashMap<String, String> mData = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private String[] mKeys;
    public HashMapAdapter(HashMap<String, String> data){
        mData  = data;
        mKeys = mData.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(mKeys[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String key = mKeys[pos];
        String Value = getItem(pos).toString();

        //do your view stuff here

        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateData(HashMap<String, String> updatedData){
       mData  = updatedData;
       mKeys = updatedData.keySet().toArray(new String[data.size()]);
       //notifying dataset changed
       notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

3- change your showEmployee() method

```
private void showEmployee(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_ISSUE_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jo.getString(TAG_STORE_NAME);
            String name = jo.getString(TAG_ISSUE);
            String describe = jo.getString(TAG_DESCRIBE);

            HashMap<String,String> employees = new HashMap<>();
            employees.put(TAG_STORE_NAME,id);
            employees.put(TAG_ISSUE,name);
            employees.put(TAG_DESCRIBE,describe);
            list.add(employees);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter = new HashMapAdapter(list);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

4- Write an update method

```
private void updateAdapter((HashMap<String, String> updatedData){
//This will update the adapter data and will call the notifyDatasetChanged
apater.updatedData(updatedData);

}
```